# Developing with Eclipse, Visual Studio .NET and Xcode - 13" or 15" Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos

I have some Xcode (iPhone/iPad) development on the horizon and will also be doing a bit of Eclipse (Java) and .NET development in between. Since I'll be running a VM for the Windows stuff, I think a Macbook Pro is the way to go.

What I am wondering is, does the 13" Pro have enough screen real estate to make development at least a little enjoyable? I looked at the AIR and whilst it has better resolution than the 13" Pro, it of course lacks in terms of RAM etc. As a consultant I will probably be carrying this thing around quite a lot, so would rather not go with the 15".

I will be adding the SSD option to the Pro.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not particularly sure whether this is on-topic.

Comment: Definitely a hardware question... it would be better suited on the apple stackexchange or superuser, maybe even programmers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it certainly is possible and still enjoyable (my experience is with NetBeans) to work on a 13" MBP (at 1280x800) it does get a little constrained at times. The NetBeans interface was been cleaned up a lot and works quite nicely, but sometimes still suffers, like Eclipse, of having too many little tool windows (eg. project navigation, function/class explorer etc) which quickly clutter up the display.

It is known that programmers can never have enough screen real estate and it really is more pleasant to work with a bigger screen (I used to have a 15" MBP, when I upgraded, I was constrained by the wallet :( ). While 13" certainly is more portable, I found the 15" be be quite light compared to PCs of the same size (most of the time), and it wasn't painful to carry around.

My current ideal (i.e. what I am lusting after) is a 15" matte 1680x1050 MBP. If you're not going to have a large n external display handy often, I think the more screen estate you can gather, the more you should take.

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched from a 15" MBP to a 13" MBA and really enjoy it. SSD is absolutely key, so good thing that you're adding it.

I'd be reticent to go with any lower resolution than the 15" MBP / 13" MBA offers personally.  So if you want to go with the Pro, stick with the 15". Screen real estate gets to be a little tight when debugging in either Eclipse or Visual Studio.  I imagine it would be really cumbersome to work with on the 13" MBP.

As mentioned, the question may get more feedback on the other SE sites.  Good luck with your purchase!

Comment: Thanks all. Posted it on the apple stackexchange. Apologies, didn't know that existed.